# Not Able to get the full path of the file

Tags: perl

I have written a script which will do :

1. Search a file recursively
2. Get the unique(desired one) file
3. Crate a directory on remotely placed server
4. copy this files in respective directory

**OS: Windows7**

I got stuck at 4 steps (copy this files in respective directory),because i am unable to get the full path of the file which i want to copy.

**Error : Use of uninitialized value $full_path in print at New_UIbug_parser.pl line 70**

**One more thing i would like to add is files are placed in different directories.**

Here is my porg:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy;


my $path = $ARGV[0];
my @UniqueAnr = ();
my %seen = ();
my $foundAnr;
find({ wanted => \&GetappropriateFile }, $path);
my @all_file;
my $file_name;
sub GetappropriateFile
{
  my $file = $_;

  if (-f $file && $file =~ /traces[_d+]/)
       {
              #my $line;
              $file_name = $File::Find::name;
              open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "cannot open file:$!\n";
              my @all_lines =<$fh>;
              my $i=0;
              foreach my $check (@all_lines){
            if( $i < 10){
                  if($check =~ /Cmd line\:\s+com\.android\..*/){
                  #print"$file_name\n";
                   push(@all_file,$file);
                  #push(@all_file,$file_name);
                 }  
                 $i++;
            }
            else{
                 last;
                }
                  #print "$file\n";
                  close($fh);

        }

    }

} 

foreach my $all_anr_file (@all_file)
{
unless ($seen{$all_anr_file}) 
    {
       # if we get here, we have not seen it before
        push(@UniqueAnr, $all_anr_file);
        $seen{$all_anr_file}++;

    }
}




for my $anr_file (@UniqueAnr)
{
chomp($anr_file);
print "$anr_file\n";
my $full_path = <$path.*/$anr_file>;
print $full_path;
(my $dir = $anr_file) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
my $new_dir = File::Spec->catdir('\\\\star\Source_Temp\test', $dir);
#print"$new_dir\n";
#make_path($new_dir);
copy($full_path, $new_dir) or die "Copy failed for file $anr_file: $!";

}
```

Comment: Which one is line 70?

Comment: my $full_path = <$path.*/$anr_file>; this line is the one

Comment: I think it's the one below as that has a `print`. But there's the obvious problem.

Comment: my problem is i have googled a lot but could not get the exact result :( till now. that how to get the absolute path for those file which are placed in different folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `wanted` sub you can access the full path of the file you are currently looking with `$File::Find::name`. See [the docs of File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind#The-wanted-function).

That means you don't really need all this stuff you have below your find. You can do it all in the `wanted` function.

---

Also note that you can use `uniq` from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils#uniq-LIST) to replace your `foreach` and `%seen` solution.

Comment: Thanku so much .. for helping me . I shall they way u suggested to me :)